# FeathersJS - Making sure only the user that registers gets "users created"

Tags: feathersjs

I would like to make sure that only the socket which sends a registration / "users create" message gets the according "users created" response. There is a simple example for that in the documentation looking like this:

```
// Publish the `created` event to admins and the user that sent it
app.service('users').publish('created', (data, context) => {
  return [
    app.channel('admins'),
    app.channel(app.channels).filter(connection =>
      connection.user._id === context.params.user._id
    )
  ];
});
```

However this is not working for me. If I log the context.params object, this simply looks like this when registering a new user:

```
{ query: {},
  route: {},
  connection: { provider: 'socketio' },
  provider: 'socketio' }
```

Accordingly, the appropriate connection does not get the event. Am I missing something here? Do I have to add something in the registration process for this to work? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to not worry about dispatching the real-time event to that user at all. If the same connection is already calling `.create` the result from that promise (`.create(data).then(userData => {})`) will be the same as the dispatched event.

If you'd still like to have a newly created user join certain channels you can use `params.connection` in an after hook as shown in [this issue](https://github.com/feathersjs/docs/issues/1191):

```
app.service('users').hooks({
  after: {
    create(context) {
      const { params: { connection }, result } = context;

      if(connection) {
        context.app.channel(`user/${result.id}`).join(connection);
      }

      return context;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: How can I make sure to do the same for custom events? In this case the context object does not have a reference to the user, so I cannot check every connection if the user id is the same or am I wrong?

Comment: I don't think there is a way around making sure that your custom event data somehow contains the information you need (e.g. adding the user in a ES6 Symbol property).

Comment: Okay, too bad. Maybe this is something for the future, so that it is possible to use hooks with custom events. As the auth hook provides the user data to the context, this issue would also be gone with that possibility. Thanks anyways for the fast answer!